# Resurrect NPC without corpse

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've only recently noticed that the woman who runs Warmaiden's in Whiterun seemingly is missing. Possibly she was killed in the vampire attacks (having dawnguard and all). I do not see her body anywhere so I am looking for some "restore / reset character" command, rather than just "resurrect".

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Related: [I don't want NPCs to get killed by Vampire Attacks. How do I do this?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/97715/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja good call for a solution to the root of my problem here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed it myself.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs

By basically walking through all the steps for "finding missing NPCs" I first got an invisible/ dead version of her and then resurrected that. Works now

Comment: The problem with leaving NPCs dead is that with Dawnguard add-on, you start to see increased attacks by levelled vampires, who will quickly wipe out town NPCs. One party of Master Vampire plus two thralls killed all the NPCs in the common market area of Riften in my game, as well 4 or 5 in the entry way of Whiterun.

Comment: @nosf That is precisely how I assume my NPC got killed as well.

Comment: @Mark You can accept your own answer, so other people can better see that this worked :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Console commands (PC only)

PC players can use the console commands `prid <RefID>` and `resurrect 1` to bring a dead NPC back to life. To find the RefID of an [NPC](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs), you can look it up on the [UESP wiki](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs). `prid` is a command that targets an entity, such as an NPC.

For example, for [Adrianne Avenicci](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Adrianne_Avenicci) (the woman who runs Warmaiden's in Whiterun), enter `prid 1A67C` and then `resurrect 1`. You can find more information on console commands here: https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console.

<sup>In cases where there is a visible corpse, another way to target an entity without typing `prid <RefID>` is to open the console and click on the entity (for example, the NPC's corpse). This will automatically fill in the RefID of the clicked entity. This is useful if the NPC's body is visible and nearby.</sup>

#### Teleporting lost or far NPC

If the NPC is not near you or visible after you enter `resurrect 1`, you can try teleporting the NPC to your location with the `moveto player` console command. First, enter `prid <RefID>` (if you haven’t already) to target the NPC, then enter `moveto player` to move them near you. The NPC should appear next to you after this.

However, if the NPC is still missing or invisible, they might have been 'disabled' from the game (this can happen with NPCs that have been dead for a long time), which means they won't show up in the game. To fix this, enter `enable` in the console. If the NPC is still not alive, enter `resurrect 1` again.

#### Prevent NPCs from getting killed in the first place

If you are playing on PC, you can also use [console commands](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) to mark an NPC as "essential" (unkillable). To do this, follow these steps:

- Enter this console command: `setessential <base ID> 1`. Make sure you use the "base ID" of the NPC, not the "RefID". You can find the base ID of any NPC on their respective [UESP wiki article](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs). For example, for [Adrianne Avenicci](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Adrianne_Avenicci), enter `setessential 13BB9 1`.
- To undo this change, enter the same console command, but replace `1` with `0`, e.g., `setessential 13BB9 0`.

#### Mods

> Possibly she was killed in the vampire attacks (having dawnguard and all).

###### [Run For Your Lives (original / Legendary Edition - PC)](https://www.afkmods.com/index.php?/files/file/372-run-for-your-lives/) / ([Special Edition - PC](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/2272)) / [(Xbox One / Xbox Series X/S)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4143712)

This mod makes most NPCs hide indoors when there's a vampire (or dragon) attack, instead of facing them head-on and possibly getting killed.

> A small mod that makes citizens in a village or city run indoors during a dragon or vampire attack.
>
> This was born out of frustration at seeing the citizens all trying to be a hero and rushing headlong to their doom attacking dragons and vampires. Instead, the citizens will run to safety like smart people should when faced with the horrors of giant flying fire breathing lizards (or bloodthirsty undead). NPCs who live in the attack location who own a home there will retreat to it. If the attack location has an inn, NPCs who don't live there will flee to the inn, along with any NPCs who live outdoors. If no inn is present the game picks a random interior from the surrounding area and those NPCs will flee there instead.
>
> This should work for any NPCs added by mods as well, up to a limit of 150 in the area. After that, they're on their own. The NPCs chosen are first come, first serve by the game engine.
>
> Guards, members of The Companions, Vigilants of Stendarr, and the player's followers/teammates will not run, they will stand and fight. Farm animals will not run either, because they're stupid. That includes your horse.
> ...
>
> Vampires will be detected when the events that spawn them begin running.

###### [Protect Your People (original / Legendary Edition - PC)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/84394) / ([Special Edition - PC](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/10297))

> Hate it when NPCs die from pesky dragon/vampire attacks? ...Well boy have I got a mod for you. This mod saves your friendly neighbors from untimely deaths. Technically, it flags certain NPCs Protected.
>
> My mod protects:
>
> - unique named NPCs
> - all vanilla children
> - named animals - all named dogs, the Stray Dog that can follow you, the goat Lucky from Dragon Bridge, Gleda the Goat, the fox Pumpkin from Southfringe Sanctum, Frost, all Hearthfire pets, Bilgemuck, Old Salty, Lord Tusk
> - named creatures - Grok, Moira, Melka, Uderfrykte, Sinding (werewolf)

###### [Timing is Everything - Quest Delay and Timing Control (original / Legendary Edition - PC)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/38151) / ([Special Edition - PC](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/25464))

> Allows you to customize the starting conditions for various quests. You can choose to delay the start of Dragonborn, Dawnguard, or Hearthfire quests, as well as other quest events. Or you can also reduce the level requirements allowing a quest to start earlier than it normally would.
> ...
>
> Unlike the one-off quests, most of the reoccurring world encounters will allow you to adjust their settings at any time. This is the case with the Dawnguard Vampire attacks. Even if you've already begun the Dawnguard quest, you can stop further attacks by setting this value to something higher than your current level. However, I've also included settings to adjust the frequency of the random vampire attacks, which can also be used to prevent further attacks.
>
> Dawnguard: You can stop random vampire attacks from decimating the population, or allow the crisis to build by increasing the difference between the level at which the vampire attacks start and when Dawnguard recruitment begins.

###### [GET No More Dead Merchants (PS4/PS5)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3259897) / [(Xbox One / Xbox Series X/S)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3259857)

> The Dawnguard DLC is great, but one thing I hate are it's relentless vampire attacks that leave merchants dead in their wake. Once dead, there's no replacing them, causing you to travel more or sell less. Well, no more!
>
> ...As your character levels up, the vampires, mages and dragons who raid the towns get tougher, but they remain weak, making it ridiculously difficult to keep them alive. This mod has three solutions for this:
>
> (1) It protects all merchants, so only you can kill them! When their health drops to 1, they drop to one knee, and no further attacks will harm them. But be careful, because your friendly fire can still kill them. The exception to this are essential NPCs, who the game makes invulnerable to keep quests from failing. The mod adds an asterisk next to the name of each protected or essential merchant, to make it easier to recognize them.
>
> (2) It levels all merchants to a maximum level of at least three times their starting level. So they'll level up some as your character levels up, helping them stand their ground against the onslaught of raiders and monsters.
>
> (3) It levels all merchants who are potential followers to a maximum of level 90, so they'll be more helpful as partners when your character reaches higher levels.

###### [UFO - Ultimate Follower Overhaul (PC original/Legendary Edition)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14037) / [(PC Special Edition)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/10681)

UFO will allow you to set a follower to be "essential" (unkillable).

###### [No More Dead Followers (Xbox One / Xbox Series X/S)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3285503) / [(PS4/PS5)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3285861)

> Do you worry about casting a really powerful spell, going berserk with your two-handed weapon, or taking a risky bow shot because your your favorite NPC gets in the way? Worry no more! This mod makes all followers (even animal followers) immortal, so they can't be killed--not even by you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes There is one way to revive her if you are pc user follow this steps

1. open console command bar
2. type `help (name of that girl)`
3. then some names and id will shows up
4. find name of that girl and write next to it will be id
5. type in console `Player.Placeatme (id)`
6. Close The bar and that girl will be next to you.

Comment: A heads-up on the `placeatme` console command: Using that command will instantly summon a *copy* of an object or NPC at your position. Not recommended for *named* objects or NPCs. That command creates a new copy of an object/actor in the world; using it with named objects/NPCs can result in duplicates, which could cause glitches and other unwanted game behavior. [Use the `prid <RefID>` and `moveto player` commands instead](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/403412/4797).

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
recycleactor
```

if nothing else helps.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly this does?